# Mimic "command || exit" in VimL

Tags: bash, vim

In bash, a common idiom is to quit on an error in a script using the `||` (or) operator:

```
which gem &> /dev/null || { echo "Requires RubyGems."; exit }
```

What I want to do is run a Vim command and exit (qall) if the command failed, something like

```
vim -c ":Mycommand || qall"
```

Is this possible?

**Context**:

I have this bash function that I use to look up man pages:

```
# Open man pages in vim
vman() {
  vim -R \
    -c ':source $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/man.vim' \
    -c ":Man $*" \
    -c ":only" \
    -c ":setlocal nu" \
    -c ":setlocal nomodifiable" \
    -c ":map q :q<CR>"
}
```

It works great except when the man page doesn't exist. When this happens, Vim doesn't exit on failure. I'd like to do something like

```
...
-c ":Man $* || qall"
...
```

to abort.

Comment: Obvious question: why not simply `$ man foo`?

Comment: There are a lot of benefits I like about opening man pages in Vim, especially the ability to scroll with a mouse and a better color scheme (solarized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is

```
try
    " command here
catch
    qall!
endtry
```

This quits on all Vimscript errors. However, many custom commands do not actually `:throw` / `:echoerr` an error, but instead just `:echomsg` a message highlighted in red. If that's the case (and as you seem to be concerned not about the general case, but a particular `:Man` command), you need to check for any side effects of the command to tell whether it succeeded. So, if no man page came up and Vim still shows the initial scratch buffer:

```
-c ":Man $*" \
-c "if line('$') == 1 | qall! | endif" \
-c ...
```

Comment: Cool, that works. I looked up `:help line()`, but I don't quite get what condition that if statement checks.

Comment: I also changed the `qall!` to `cquit` so that I can check for an error once I get back to the bash function. Pretty handy.

Comment: The condition checks for a single line buffer. It's simplistic, but should work unless you have one-line man pages.

Comment: Even better, use `:cq` so that Vim itself returns an error code, so your Bash script can detect it as well.